# Geological correct download rates?

Tags: java, bandwidth

I want to figure out the download speed in different places, e.g. on the Australian continent and Europe. If I download a sample file from my personal server located in Europe, the download will be much faster for the European users and accordingly slower for the Kiwis (excuse me).

How to solve this geological problem figuring out the real bandwidth of a user in a different location by using Java?

I want to figure out the very maximum possible bandwidth available.

Comment: Approx 10% of Kiwis live in AU. ;)

Comment: The maximum bandwidth between countries is usually much higher than you have a available (in the tens of Gb)  You can measure latency between countries, but hopefully this doesn't impact downloads of non-trivial files too much.

Comment: I want to figure out the maximum possible available speed. So if the lets say 1MB file would be located on the Australian server for people downloading in Australia, I would get higher bandwidth (accordingly faster connection rate) than with testing a file located on an european server (slower connection rate due to geological distance)... Am I totally wrong or do i think too much?

Answer (score 0):

The 'real download speed' is the speed for a real user. So what you measure already *is* what you are looking for. The 'very maximum possible bandwidth' can be achieved by using the loopback device on `localhost`.

Comment: Wouldnt the download speed be higher if the server is located in Australia if I want to figure out the maximum possible download bandwidth? (I want to measure the time the download needs to load the file)